# Relation to one type of item through multiple fields - SQL Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to create relation between line_items and shipment.

where a line item has inbound_shipment_id and outbound_shipment_id where both these reference the same shipment model and table

```
inbound_shipment_id foreign key - shipment table -- id
outbound_shipment_id foreign key - shipment table -- id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines should set your associations correctly

```
belongs_to :inbound_shipment, class_name: 'Shipment'
belongs_to :outbound_shipment, class_name: 'Shipment'
```

**UPDATE**

In the `Shipment` model, assuming that the relationship between line_items and shipment is one to many, use the following associations

```
has_many :inbound_line_items, class_name: 'LineItem', foreign_key: :inbound_shipment_id
has_many :outbound_line_items, class_name: 'LineItem', foreign_key: :outbound_shipment_id
```